# Sign Up Not Working - Parse - Swift 2

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2

When I clicked my "Sign Up" button after typing my username and password in, my app crashes. I am new to this type of programming and I have no idea why. This is my error:

```
2015-12-08 08:37:51.477 Scoop[835:19495] -[Scoop.CustomSignUpViewController SignUp:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa383cc8220
2015-12-08 08:37:51.484 Scoop[835:19495] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Scoop.CustomSignUpViewController SignUp:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa383cc8220'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108960f45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a684deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010896956d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001088b6eea ___forwarding___ + 970
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001088b6a98 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   UIKit                               0x000000010917ee91 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
6   UIKit                               0x00000001092ea4d8 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
7   UIKit                               0x00000001092ea7a4 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
8   UIKit                               0x00000001092e98d4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
9   UIKit                               0x00000001091eced1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
10  UIKit                               0x00000001091edc06 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
11  UIKit                               0x000000010919d2fa -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
12  UIKit                               0x0000000109177abf _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010888d011 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108882f3c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001088823f3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108881e08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010bdd0ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
18  UIKit                               0x000000010917d30d UIApplicationMain + 171
19  Scoop                               0x00000001075e463d main + 109
20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b19692d start + 1
21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This is my code for my sign up action:

```
@IBAction func SignUpAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var username = self.usernameField.text
    var password = self.passwordField.text
    var confirmPassword = self.confirmPasswordField.text

    if (username?.characters.count > 4 || password?.characters.count > 5){

        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Oops!", message: "Username must be
     greater than 4 & password must be greater than 5.", delegate: self, 
     cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")
        alert.show()
    }else if (password?.characters.count !=  
  confirmPassword?.characters.count){
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Oops!", message: "Your passwords do
   not match. Try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")
        alert.show()
    }else {

        self.actInd.startAnimating()

        var newUser = PFUser()

        newUser.username = username
        newUser.password = password

        newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeed, error) -> Void in


            self.actInd.stopAnimating()

            if ((error) != nil) {

                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "\(error)", 
  delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")
                alert.show()
            }else {

                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success!", message: "You 
  have been signed up for Scoop!", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle:   
  "Okay")
                alert.show()
            }



        })



        }

    }
```

Comment: Two small things I notice in your code that you might want to look over. (This most likely wont fix your code completely)

`if (username?.characters.count > 4 || password?.characters.count > 5)`
should be `if (username?.characters.count < 5 || password?.characters.count < 6)` to fulfill what you are suggesting in the text returning if this statement equals true.

`else if (password?.characters.count !=  
  confirmPassword?.characters.count)`
This states that if you enter two different passwords for password and confirm password, but they have the same amount of characters, it's all good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your method

```
@IBAction func SignUpAction(sender: AnyObject){
```

to

```
@IBAction func SignUp(sender: AnyObject){
```

To prevent crashes like this you should read the error message carefully, it says:

> -[Scoop.CustomSignUpViewController SignUp:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...

That means that you try to call a method on your view controller which doesn't exist. Often it happens if you misspell a name of method ( you sent `SignUp` name, but in your view controller `SignUpAction`)

By the way, it would be better practice, according to guidelines, to name methods starting with lowercase character.